# Why is NSJSONSerialization parsing NSDictionary incorrectly into JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm making a POST request to a server from an IOS app and sending a JSON payload of an email and password value.

My code so far is making a `NSDictionary` and serializing it into `NSData`:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"email" : @"khush@gmail.com" , @"password" : @"mypass" };

NSData *payload = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:nil];
```

I attach the payload as part of the `request.HTTPBody`, however the server receives the following data:

> { '{"email":"khush@gmail.com", "password":"mypass"}' : ' ' }

It seems to be taking the whole string as the key and emitting a null as the value.

Any ideas/solutions to this problem? I've had a look at  but it doesn't make [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371516/incorrectly-parse-json-into-nsdictionary) sense to me.

Comment: It's not the conversion from dictionary -> JSON, it's the formatting within the HTTP request that is failing.

Comment: +1 @trojanfoe How do you "attach" the payload as a part of the HTTP body? And does your server support JSON as a part of the request's body?

Comment: Easiest way is to debug the JSON string before you attach it. If its valid then something down the line is to blame.

Comment: Try converting NSData to NSString and pass this string to server as some web developers accept json string and not object.
Example:    
 NSString *strJson = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.httpBody = strJson;

Comment: Your question is wrong. You are asking "why" and the answer is "it isn't, your problem is somewhere else".

Comment: im adding json to the body this way: request.HTTPBody = payload;

Comment: @KhushV I added an update part to my answer, HTTPBody is not designed to contain only a value, but a NSData representing a string of the kind key1=value1&key2=value2 (like GET parameters), what you are receiving: a key without an object is NORMAL given you didn't respect the key=value[&...] format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in your payload. Data is being messed up in HTTP layer. Please ensure you have following content type set in your request headers.

```
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
```

Comment: Well the server *is* receiving JSON, it's just messed-up, so I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: You are right. But if content type is mistakenly set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then it reaches as JSON but in messed up form. Lets see if this helps OP.

Comment: Holy cow! Almost a day lost with this and I had no clue. To do it in Swift 3: `request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are making something like

```
request.HTTPBody = encodedVersionOfPayload;
```

while you should be marking something more like

```
request.HTTPBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", yourKey, encodedVersionOfPayload];
```

Please show us this part of your code.

---

UPDATE

After a quick look to documentation, NSMutableURLRequest, HTTPBody property is a NSData and not a NSString,

so you have probably written

```
request.HTTPBody = payload;
```

where you should have something more like

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:payload encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *payloadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", jsonString];
request.HTTPBody = [payloadString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(not tested but should be correct, your json object should be available on your server using the key "data")